# Error in moving Backup file

Tags: sql, database-backup

I have created a backup file by SQL query like this :

> BackUp [DBName] to disk=N'Backup path'.

now i want to move it to another folder.but i recieve this error:

> Cannot copy 'Backup file name':Access is denied. Make sure the disk is not full or write protected and that the file is not currently in use.

Note : i am sure that my disk is not full and not write-protected for my user.

Answer (score 0):

It would've been created by the account used by the SQL service. So is there a chance that you don't actually have permission on the file?

Alternatively, could it be that the backup process hasn't finished completely (is it caught up verifying it or something), and that the file is locked?

Comment: thanx for your help. i solved my problem.